# Define a cell as a variable to be used in workbook reference

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to define a cell as a variable so that I can use it when calling upon a workbook.  This cell changes daily and before running this macro I create a brand new workbook with this cell as the title.

This is what I have but obviously it won't work:

```
Dim wbk As Workbook

Set wbk = "X:\myname\TESTOCD\&"Sheets("MockupHelp").Range("d29")"""
```

The cell I am referencing that changes daily is in my sheet `MockUpHelp` is `D29`.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
set wbk = workbooks.open("X:\myname\TESTOCD\" & Sheets("MockupHelp").Range("d29").value & ".xlsx")
```

Not sure if you need the .xlsx thrown on the tail end but that should give you the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method would be to declare your variable as a Name, using the Name Manager in the Formulas ribbon. Example: declare "MY_TEST_RANGE" to be equal to $D$29. When you refer to it in your code, you can refer directly to MY_TEST_RANGE, as you would any other variable.

This has the advantage of updating automatically whenever rows are inserted etc. within your workbook.

If you instead mean that people need to manually change the cell being referred to, there are other (similar) methods available let me know if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wbk As Workbook

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("X:\myname\TESTOCD\" & _
                      Sheets("MockupHelp").Range("D29").Value)
```